# mongodb find by multiple array items

Tags: arrays, search, mongodb

If I have a record like this;

```
{
  "text": "text goes here",
  "words": ["text", "goes", "here"]
}
```

How can I match multiple words from it in MongoDB? When matching a single word I can do this;

```
db.find({ words: "text" })
```

But when I try this for multiple words, it doesn't work;

```
db.find({ words: ["text", "here"] })
```

I'm guessing that by using an array, it tries to match the entire array against the one in the record, rather than matching the individual contents.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Depends on whether you're trying to find documents where `words` contains both elements (`text` and `here`) using [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/all/):

```
db.things.find({ words: { $all: ["text", "here"] }});
```

or either of them (`text` or `here`) using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
db.things.find({ words: { $in: ["text", "here"] }});
```

Comment: This helped me too, I needed it to find an object ID in an array, and where something like $in: [ ObjectId("4f9f2c336b810d0cf0000017") ] failed, $in: [ "4f9f2c336b810d0cf0000017" ] worked

Comment: you can also find another way to do this in mangodb support page http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#indexes-on-sub-documents and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#multikey-indexes

Comment: Is this better than looping the array and performing single find()?

Comment: @RohitNair, It's clear to read as well as faster when doc size is big.

Comment: db.things.find({ words: { $elemMatch: { $in: ["text","here"] }})