# MongoDB: How to find out if an array field contains an element?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections.  The first collection contains students:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015cf"), "name" : "John" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d0"), "name" : "Sam" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d1"), "name" : "Chris" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d2"), "name" : "Joe" }
```

The second collection contains courses:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51780fb5c9c41825e3e21fc4"),
        "name" : "CS 101",
        "students" : [
                ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015cf"),
                ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d0"),
                ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d2")
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51780fb5c9c41825e3e21fc5"),
        "name" : "Literature",
        "students" : [
                ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d0"),
                ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d0"),
                ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d2")
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51780fb5c9c41825e3e21fc6"),
        "name" : "Physics",
        "students" : [
                ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015cf"),
                ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d0")
        ]
}
```

Each course document contains `students` array which has a list of students registered for the course.  When a student views a course on a web page he needs to see if he has already registered for the course or not.  In order to do that, when the `courses` collection gets queried on the student's behalf, we need to find out if `students` array already contains the student's ObjectId.  Is there a way to specify in the projection of a find query to retrieve student `ObjectId` from `students` array only if it is there?

I tried to see if I could $elemMatch operator but it is geared towards an array of sub-documents.  I understand that I could use aggregation framework but it seems that it would be on overkill in this case.  Aggregation framework would probably not be as fast as a single find query.  Is there a way to query course collection to so that the returned document could be in a form similar to this?

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51780fb5c9c41825e3e21fc4"),
        "name" : "CS 101",
        "students" : [
                ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d0"),
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[**edit** based on this now being possible in recent versions]

[Updated Answer] You can query the following way to get back the name of class and the student id only if they are already enrolled.

```
db.student.find({},
 {_id:0, name:1, students:{$elemMatch:{$eq:ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015cf")}}})
```

and you will get back what you expected:

```
{ "name" : "CS 101", "students" : [ ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015cf") ] }
{ "name" : "Literature" }
{ "name" : "Physics", "students" : [ ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015cf") ] }
```

[Original Answer] It's not possible to do what you want to do currently.  This is unfortunate because you would be able to do this if the student was stored in the array as an object.  In fact, I'm a little surprised you are using just ObjectId() as that will *always* require you to look up the students if you want to display a list of students enrolled in a particular course (look up list of Id's first then look up names in the students collection - two queries instead of one!)

If you were storing (as an example) an Id and name in the course array like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51780fb5c9c41825e3e21fc6"),
        "name" : "Physics",
        "students" : [
                {id: ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015cf"), name: "John"},
                {id: ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d0"), name: "Sam"}
        ]
}
```

Your query then would simply be:

```
db.course.find( { }, 
                { students : 
                    { $elemMatch : 
                       { id : ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d0"), 
                         name : "Sam" 
                       } 
                    } 
                } 
);
```

If that student was only enrolled in CS 101 you'd get back:

```
{ "name" : "Literature" }
{ "name" : "Physics" }
{
    "name" : "CS 101",
    "students" : [
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015cf"),
            "name" : "John"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming my thoughts on not being able to query simple arrays as well as arrays of sub-documents.  I guess I will have to re-evaluate my schema.
Do you know if 10Gen is planning to address this issue?

Comment: I was not able to find a Jira ticket for this in jira.mongodb.org and nothing gets scheduled for a release without a ticket there, so I would say definitely not any time soon.

Comment: What about using $all as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145523/mongodb-find-by-multiple-array-items

Comment: $all is an operator for querying - querying is not an issue, the issue is returning so it's projection operators that we are discussing.

Comment: The problem with storing both the name and object id in the `course` collection is that you then have the students name stored in multiple places, which could potentially get out of sync. In this case your query would return incomplete data. If server load and hardware are not stretched very thin, the extra query to get the name may be preferable. You could still store student `ObjectId`s as an objectto allow the OP's query: `{"id":...}`

Comment: given how infrequently people's names change, it seems that optimizing performance for that extremely rare occurrence is unlikely to be right.  Optimize for the common case - extra lookup is saved on every single query.

Comment: not sure if anyone looks, but there is a simple find query with projection that will allow this in all recent versions (original answer from over two years ago didn't seem to work this way).

Comment: Asya, Thank you for following up.  People still look at this question.

Answer (score 23):

It seems like the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/) operator would serve your purposes just fine.

You could do something like this (pseudo-query):

```
if (db.courses.find({"students" : {"$in" : [studentId]}, "course" : courseId }).count() > 0) {
  // student is enrolled in class
}
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `"course" : courseId` clause and get back a set of all classes the student is enrolled in.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it will return a document from courses collection only if the student has registered for the course.  If the student has not registered, a second query would be required.  This is not efficient.

Comment: The second query would be to retrieve the student's object id? But wouldn't that be known already (after all, you are using it to make the first query).

Comment: The end goal is to retrieve the course document and have a flag to indicate if the student has registered for it.  The query you provided will retrieve the course document only if the student has registered for it.  If the student has not registered for the course then another query is needed to retrieve the course document.

Comment: Gotcha. How about you run the first query without the `$in` clause - you now have the course document. You can now check the document for the student without making another query to Mongo. For example, if the client is a python app, you can check `if ObjectId(studentId) in course.students :`

Comment: The I have to fetch the entire array from the server.  This may get expensive if it has a lot of students.  My hunch is that something is wrong with the data model but I don't know what it is.  It is weird that arrays of sub-documents can be filtered with $elemMatch but there is not anything for arrays of plain data.  Or may be it is just me.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the data-model. I suspect there is no real way to achieve what you want without two queries because, at the end of the day, you are asking your database two questions: give me the course document AND is the student enrolled in the course. Even in a traditional relational db, you would face the same issue.

Comment: But isn't the whole advantage of mongo is not to have to use 2 queries but do everything in one?

Comment: Late response (sorry!), but no that never has been the goal of Mongo. Mongo is to store non-relational, schemaless data objects. AFAIK, it makes no attempt to reduce the number of queries needed.

Comment: even later response - absolutely in MongoDB schema design is all about minimizing the number of separate queries to the database. Good rule of thumb is store data the way you need to use it - luckily for this use case, there is a simple find that does that - returns all courses with a field indicating whether the student is already enrolled in it. The problem with this answer is that if there are 50 courses to choose from, you are suggesting running 50 count queries. Plus the $in operator is absolutely unnecessary as it's only needed if you were listing multiple student id values in the array

Answer (score 0):

**I am trying to explain by putting problem statement and solution to it. I hope it will help**

*Problem Statement:*

Find all the published products, whose name like ABC Product or PQR Product, and price should be less than 15/-

*Solution:*

Below are the conditions that need to be taken care of

1. Product price should be less than 15
2. Product name should be either ABC Product or PQR Product
3. Product should be in published state.

Below is the statement that applies above criterion to create query and fetch data.

```
$elements = $collection->find(
             Array(
                [price] => Array( [$lt] => 15 ),
                [$or] => Array(
                            [0]=>Array(
                                    [product_name]=>Array(
                                       [$in]=>Array(
                                            [0] => ABC Product,
                                            [1]=> PQR Product
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                ),
                [state]=>Published
                )
            );
```