# fetching documents based on nested subdoc array value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get all documents in a collection based on a subdocument array values. This is my data structure in the collection i'm seeking:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('...'),
    name: "my event",
    members:
    [
        {
            _id: ObjectId('...'),
            name: "family",
            users: [ObjectId('...'),ObjectId('...'),ObjectId('...')]
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId('...'),
            name: "work",
            users: [ObjectId('...'),ObjectId('...'),ObjectId('...')]
        }
    ]
}
```

I should point out that the schema of these objects are defined like so:

Events:

```
{
    name: { type: String },
    members: {type: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'MemberGroup' }], default:[] }
}
```

MemberGroup:

```
{
    name: { type: String },
    users: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
}
```

and of course User is just an arbitrary object with an id.

**What i'm trying to fetch:** i want to retrieve all events which has a specific user id in its member.users field.

i'm not sure if its event possible in a single call but here is what i've tried:

```
var userId = new mongoose.Schema.ObjectId('57d9503ef10d5ffc08d6b8cc');
events.find({members: { $elemMatch : { users: { $in: [userId]} } }})
```

this syntax work but return no elements even though i know there are matching elements (using robomongo to visualize the db)

Comment: The syntax is wrong - 4 left curly and 5 right curly (also missing right closing brackets). I fixed the syntax and it works: `db.events.find({ members: { $elemMatch: { users: { $in: [userId] } } }})`

Comment: @Tom nope, that was just a copy paste typo

Comment: I understand, but as I said, when I run this query it works. so i guess you are forgetting something else...

Answer (score 0):

So after a long search in stackoverflow i came across the good answare here:

[MongoDB: How to find out if an array field contains an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198429/mongodb-how-to-find-out-if-an-array-field-contains-an-element)

my query changed to the following which gave me my desired result:

```
var userId = new mongoose.Schema.ObjectId('57d9503ef10d5ffc08d6b8cc');
events.find({}, {members: { $elemMatch : { users: { $eq: userId} } }})
```

notice the use of the second find parameter to specify the query limit instead of the first one (which is odd)