# mongodb search for particular string

Tags: python, mongodb

How to filter the string 682186760 in db using python

collection posts:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58f9efa9c9948f002449b8f7"),
    "a" : [ 
        "682186760"
    ]
}
```

for e.g

```
if "682186760" in posts.find():
    print("yes")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How to find out if an array field contains an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198429/mongodb-how-to-find-out-if-an-array-field-contains-an-element)

Comment: simply use the query posts.find({a: 682186760}), it doesn't make sense to me that you are doing `if "682186760" in posts.find():
    print("yes")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the mongo Query for that:

```
db.collection.find(
   { a: { $elemMatch: {'$eq':'682186760'} } }
)
```

PyMongo Query will be :

```
db.collection.find(
       { 'a': { '$elemMatch': {'$eq':'682186760'} } }
    )
```

You will get cursor where you can find out all the elements which matches your query.