# Meteor, dynamic subscription parameters

Tags: angular, meteor, publish-subscribe

I am trying to subscribe to a list of user teams including an extra dynamic team. The id of the last one is passed by parameter to the subscription, like that:

```
MeteorObservable.subscribe('user.teams', extraTeamId).subscribe(() => {
    this.findUserTeams();
});
```

The extraTeamId var is constantly changing on my service component, and I need to have this dynamic team on my client collection every time this var changes.

My first question is: if I change the value of this variable on my component, should the publish receive this new value, or it is never updated on server?

If Meteor wasn't supposed to work like that, there is any other good options?

I am also using Angular2 for that.

Comment: Look for Reactive Changes section in this [link](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/search-sort-pagination-and-reactive-vars), I think it will match your need

Comment: Thanks for that, I haven't seen this implementation before, but I liked! Maybe I will try a simpler version of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get new value then you have to unsubscribe from last subscription and again subscribe to new values. you can do it like this in angular 2 meteor.

on server side publish

```
   if (Meteor.isServer) {
     Meteor.publish('user.teams', function(option : string) {
                console.log(option);   // you will get your dynamic param value in option
                return findUserTeams.find({"team": option});  // apply your query here
        });
     }
```

and on client side you can do something like this.

```
     userteamdata: Observable < any[] > ;
     userteamSub: Subscription;

      this.userteamSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('user.teams', extraTeamId).subscribe(() => {
    this.userteamdata = findUserTeam.find({}).zone();
  });
```

now when your extraTeamId value change you can detect that change 
       and do something like this

```
valuechangefunction(){

    if (this.userteamSub) {
            this.userteamSub.unsubscribe();
          }
      this.userteamSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('user.teams', extraTeamId).subscribe(() => {
            this.userteamdata = findUserTeam.find({}).zone();
          });
}
```

i hope this will help :)

Comment: That's good, I was trying to avoid this (unsubscribe and subscribe again), but I think it will be necessary.

I am thinking about use 2 subscriptions, one with the user teams (may have many) and keep that subscription alive. This way will prevent the overhead of removing and resending the collection data to the client.

And the other subscription will be for the extra team only, this one will unsubscribe and resubscribe everytime it changes. What do you think?

Comment: @HenriqueRotava i think there is one more solution to your problem instead of 2 subscriptions you can add all your team in one array and onchange add dynamic id also into this array and search all using $in mongdb query. publish all teams from server side. here is the link to mondb query that you will need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145523/mongodb-find-by-multiple-array-items .