# Querying an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Test data

```
db.multiArr.insert({"ID" : "fruit1","Keys" : ["carrot", "banana"]})
db.multiArr.insert({"ID" : "fruit2","Keys" : ["apple", "orange"]})
db.multiArr.insert({"ID" : "fruit2","Keys" : ["apple"]})
```

How do I query for Keys in ["apple"，"other"]?
Need

```
 ({"ID" : "fruit2","Keys" : ["apple"]})
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try `db.multiArr.find({Keys:{$in:["apple", "orange", "carrot"]}})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb find by multiple array items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145523/mongodb-find-by-multiple-array-items)

Comment: first doc has a nested array, is this a typo or design?

Comment: Modified question

Comment: A little different。
query：db.multiArr.find({"Keys":{$all:["apple"]}})
result:
  ({"ID" : "fruit2","Keys" : ["apple", "orange"]})
  ({"ID" : "fruit2","Keys" : ["apple"]})

Not needed： ({"ID" : "fruit2","Keys" : ["apple", "orange"]})

Comment: What is "other" in the query ? For just apples you can use  `db.multiArr.find({Keys:["apple"]})`

Comment: `result:`{ 
        "ID" : "fruit2", 
        "Keys" : [
            "apple", 
            "orange"
        ]
    }
    { 
        "ID" : "fruit2", 
        "Keys" : [
            "apple"
        ]
    }

`Not needed：`
 `"Keys" : [
            "apple", 
            "orange"
        ]`

Comment: ## result:
`{ "ID" : "fruit2", "Keys" : [ "apple", "orange" ] } { "ID" : "fruit2", "Keys" : [ "apple" ] }`
## Not needed： 
`"Keys" : [ "apple", "orange" ]`