# I have a query statement using a string array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
var chatIds = ["XWNGstSqtDprdMqnC",
               "twqExeDofj5J492Q6", 
               "M77enWFMDCABKx3Goq5gjsToaBLDLcRs7b", 
               "aSKprL5omjCEiR4nSq5gjsToaBLDLcRs7b"]

var dbname = 'rocketchat';
var db = db.getSiblingDB(dbname);

for (var i=0; i < chatIds.length; i++) {
    var cursor = db.rocketchat_message.find({"rid":chatIds[i]})
    printjson(cursor.next());
}
```

Hello, I have an error while writing the JavaScript for mongodb.
The above JavaScript file
It was executed through '**mongo --quiet chat_content.js**'.
The first result of the array is output, but the second one has the following error.

```
{
    "_id" : "9yvRFCTi4YZzGdgH7",
    "t" : "r",
    "rid" : "XWNGstSqtDprdMqnC",
    "ts" : ISODate("2017-01-17T08:25:24.073Z"),
    "msg" : "it_team",
    "u" : {
        "_id" : "twqExeDofj5J492Q6",
        "username" : "sumin_kim"
    },
    "groupable" : false,
    "_updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-01-17T08:25:24.073Z")
}
2018-10-18T18:23:44.375+0900 error hasNext: false at 
src/mongo/shell/query.js:127
failed to load: chat_content.js
```

The output I wanted was to output all of the dialogue through looping, but there seems to be something I do not understand in writing JavaScript. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a javascript syntax error, but a problem I have not noticed in the mongodb shell method.
Here is right method for my case.

```
db.rocketchat_message.find({"rid":{$in:["XWNGstSqtDprdMqnC", "twqExeDofj5J492Q6"]}}).pretty();
```

And i had referenced this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145523/mongodb-find-by-multiple-array-items).