# Individual search result in multiple values in arrays

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have following model:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d61aaf8108e185191552bbb"),
    "serials" : [
        "e127av48-0697-4977-b096-5ce79c89a414",
        "d163f80a-55ff-40fe-90b4-331ece5bebd5",
        "4740021f-e9b5-4ca5-bf0e-8554c123bb94",
        "320ffd42-f101-4b1d-8ff4-80bc693a29e6",
        "fef5e68b-aed0-4a96-9488-7941c41d1c1f",
        "2c0752ba-bf7a-4a3b-bd9f-14db4b2f8bae",
        "6c5ff44d-5979-4bff-af12-9e6d282c3789",
        "9c91bf91-72d7-4b71-827b-924947d6e93d",
        "fb34b28e-afb1-4b6a-a3c1-5a1fe44246ee",
        "91ab22ef-702f-4cbd-8919-a67a2b9a684c",
        "ee1a7cb2-e088-47e6-a824-c8697df7d94c",
        "0dc4c687-4db2-481e-a1a6-491320dede11",
        "34612148-3e01-44ee-b262-de2035e63691",
        "5ba85baf-e48a-40af-8578-55ff1a873c76",
        "19fe3672-b6cb-4bb6-8d21-93412b938584",
        "1d0d6f6d-1b49-461b-8661-ecbf43a6595e",
        "d9a5455c-65ee-45e1-ae49-33cc15dec841",
        "4a690a00-a76c-4d3e-aee3-78b2bb731b0c",
        "ae331830-40b4-457c-8cc4-5d548f769c3e",
        "fe3e460b-c89d-4ace-8a36-5ba2b53bf4d0",
        "2cc6a2a0-e029-475f-a7fc-a46a79afb605",
        "a7d07767-eada-4ce3-b083-9b048e9ae9f4"
    ],
    "name" : "ApiCard",
    "producer" : "Farmina",
    "form" : "syrop",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I would like to retrive documents (multiple) from collection based on this serial numbers ("serials" field). For example i am finding:

```
[
        "e127av48-0697-4977-b096-5ce79c89a414",
        "d163f80a-55ff-40fe-90b4-331ece5bebd5",
        "4740021f-e9b5-4ca5-bf0e-8554c123bb94",
        "key that doesn't exist",
]
```

We have to assume that one of the serial number doesn't exist, so would like to get information for **individual** serial, expected output:

```
[
    {
        "serial":"e127av48-0697-4977-b096-5ce79c89a414",
        "doc":{
            ....whole document where above serial is in array field "serials"
        }
    },
    {
        "serial":"e127av48-0697-4977-b096-5ce79c89a414",
        "doc":{
            ....whole document where above serial is in array field "serials"
        }
    },
    {
        "serial":"e127av48-0697-4977-b096-5ce79c89a414",
        "doc":{
            ....whole document where above serial is in array field "serials"
        }
    },
    {
        "serial":"key that doesn't exist",
        "doc": null
    }
]
```

I was trying the simplest solution - [mongodb find by multiple array items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145523/mongodb-find-by-multiple-array-items), but unfortunately it'doesn't return info for individual serial number. I'am not sure it's possible to prepare this kind of query. I think some complex aggregation could perform it, but i don't even know this kind of pipelines.

Of course, i can get simple solution by using multiple aggregate or even find, but it could impact on performance, when application will be looking for 10000 records per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can do the trick:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $limit:1
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "serialsToSearch":[
                    "e127av48-0697-4977-b096-5ce79c89a414",
                    "d163f80a-55ff-40fe-90b4-331ece5bebd5",
                    "4740021f-e9b5-4ca5-bf0e-8554c123bb94",
                    "key that doesn't exist",
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$serialsToSearch"
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            "from":"collection",
            "let":{
                "serial":"$serialsToSearch"
            },
            "pipeline":[
                {
                    $match:{
                        $expr:{
                            $in:["$$serial","$serials"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project:{
                        "serials":0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as":"searialsLookup"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:{
            "path":"$searialsLookup",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true
        }
    },  
    {
        $project:{
            "serial":"$serialsToSearch",
            "doc":{
                $ifNull:["$searialsLookup",null]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data Set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d61aaf8108e185191552bbb"),
    "serials" : [
        "e127av48-0697-4977-b096-5ce79c89a414",
        "d163f80a-55ff-40fe-90b4-331ece5bebd5",
        "4740021f-e9b5-4ca5-bf0e-8554c123bb94",
        "320ffd42-f101-4b1d-8ff4-80bc693a29e6",
        "fef5e68b-aed0-4a96-9488-7941c41d1c1f",
        "2c0752ba-bf7a-4a3b-bd9f-14db4b2f8bae",
        "6c5ff44d-5979-4bff-af12-9e6d282c3789",
        "9c91bf91-72d7-4b71-827b-924947d6e93d",
        "fb34b28e-afb1-4b6a-a3c1-5a1fe44246ee",
        "91ab22ef-702f-4cbd-8919-a67a2b9a684c",
        "ee1a7cb2-e088-47e6-a824-c8697df7d94c",
        "0dc4c687-4db2-481e-a1a6-491320dede11",
        "34612148-3e01-44ee-b262-de2035e63691",
        "5ba85baf-e48a-40af-8578-55ff1a873c76",
        "19fe3672-b6cb-4bb6-8d21-93412b938584",
        "1d0d6f6d-1b49-461b-8661-ecbf43a6595e",
        "d9a5455c-65ee-45e1-ae49-33cc15dec841",
        "4a690a00-a76c-4d3e-aee3-78b2bb731b0c",
        "ae331830-40b4-457c-8cc4-5d548f769c3e",
        "fe3e460b-c89d-4ace-8a36-5ba2b53bf4d0",
        "2cc6a2a0-e029-475f-a7fc-a46a79afb605",
        "a7d07767-eada-4ce3-b083-9b048e9ae9f4"
    ],
    "name" : "ApiCard",
    "producer" : "Farmina",
    "form" : "syrop",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "serial" : "e127av48-0697-4977-b096-5ce79c89a414",
    "doc" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d61aaf8108e185191552bbb"),
        "name" : "ApiCard",
        "producer" : "Farmina",
        "form" : "syrop",
        "__v" : 0
    }
}
{
    "serial" : "d163f80a-55ff-40fe-90b4-331ece5bebd5",
    "doc" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d61aaf8108e185191552bbb"),
        "name" : "ApiCard",
        "producer" : "Farmina",
        "form" : "syrop",
        "__v" : 0
    }
}
{
    "serial" : "4740021f-e9b5-4ca5-bf0e-8554c123bb94",
    "doc" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d61aaf8108e185191552bbb"),
        "name" : "ApiCard",
        "producer" : "Farmina",
        "form" : "syrop",
        "__v" : 0
    }
}
{ "serial" : "key that doesn't exist", "doc" : null }
```

*Note: The query won't give expected output if the `collection` would be empty.*

## Aggregation stages details:

- **STAGE I**: Limiting the records to 1, as initially, our motive is to inject the input array in aggregation. The injection would be done in no time.
- **STAGE II**: Projecting the input array as `serialsToSearch`
- **STAGE III**: Now we have the input array as a field, we can unwind it
- **STAGE IV**: Lookup in the same collection with each field of the input array and check if the searched serial is present in `serials` array
- **STAGE V**: unwinding the lookup output
- **STAGE VI**: Projecting fields as per the response required.

Comment: I have one question, how to remove field "serials" from "doc" (output) ?