# How to make and requests in mongodb queries

Tags: mongodb

I've worked on this for about an hour now and I can't figure anything out that works so sorry if this is obvious.

I want my query to only return results where every result matches, but right now it returns a result if at least one match is found.

My document looks like this...

```
{
    country: 'Great Britain',
    data: [
        {
            school: 'King Alberts',
            staff: [
                {
                    name: 'John',
                    age: 37,
                    position: 'Head Teacher'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Grace',
                    age: 63,
                    position: 'Retired'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Bob',
                    age: 25,
                    position: 'Receptionist'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            school: 'St Johns',
            staff: [
                {
                    name: 'Alex',
                    age: 22,
                    position: 'Head of Drama'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Grace',
                    age: 51,
                    position: 'English Teacher'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Jack',
                    age: 33,
                    position: 'Receptionist'
                }
            ]
        },
        // ... more schools
    ]
}
```

The query I'm currently making looks like...

```
{ 'data.staff.name': { $in: names } }
```

and the 'names' array that is being provided looks like ['Bob', 'Grace', 'John', 'Will', 'Tom']. Currently both schools are being returned when I make this query, I think it's because the 'names' array contains 'Grace' which is a name present at both schools and so the document it matching. Does anyone know if there's a query I could make so mongodb only returns the school object if every name in the 'names' array is a member of staff at the school?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb find by multiple array items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145523/mongodb-find-by-multiple-array-items) You can use $all instead of $in

Comment: It doesn't because sometimes the 'names' array that is provided has additional names like in the example I provided. The first school should still be returned for this array though, as it contains all the staff. If I used the $all operator, it would return nothing as the school doesn't have 'Will' or 'Tom', which is why I can't use the $or operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the aggregation pipeline for this, after matching the document we'll just filter out the none matching arrays, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "data.staff.name": {
        $in: names
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: {
                  "$setIntersection": [
                    "$$this.staff.name",
                    names
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                $size: "$$this.staff"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X9SuKJ7MBFq)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this will match any results where the array also contains non-matches as well as all the staff names. For example, if the 'names' array was ['Bob', 'Grace', 'John', 'Will', 'Tom']. This wouldn't return either schools if I use the $all operator.

Comment: Ah gotcha, you want the inverse. i will edit my answer

Comment: For an array of ['Bob', 'Grace', 'John', 'Will', 'Tom'], I need the query to return any schools where every staff member's name is in this array. If there are additional names in the array, they can be ignored. In this case, a school with the staff 'Will' and 'John' would be returned, but a school with the staff 'Will' and 'Fin' would not be.

Comment: Edited. now reflects the proper logic

Comment: Yeah that worked! Thank you so much, I was starting to think this couldn't be done.

Comment: `$setIntersection` is a powerful function; learn it, explore it.