Pymongo - fetch documents by multiple tags
I need to fetch documents given a list of tags, but I am having trouble finding the right  syntax. For example, I have this collection:
{
    "name": "Mike",
    "roll_no": "45",
    "branch" : "75",
    "tags": [tag1, tag2],
}

{
    "name": "Karl",
    "roll_no": "4",
    "branch" : "5",
    "tags": [tag3, tag2],
}

I am using this command collection_name.find_one({"tags": ['tag1', 'tag2']} ) to retrieve both documents (e.g. Mike and Karl), but it is not working.
Any idea about what I am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Are you actually using find_one as opposed to find? As the name suggests, find_one will only return 1 or zero results.

Hi - I used find, but in return I get the object address: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7c39fd7dfdf0>. How do I get a readable object ?
Thank you!

@Sim81 if you're only expecting a few small objects, you can just do list(find(...)). Otherwise if you iterate over the cursor you'll get each of the found objects in sequence

thank you for your suggestion, it works for one tag search. What if I have a list of tags like in my original example?, for example:
list(collection_name.find({"tags": ['tag1',' tag2' ] } )

@Sim81 when doing array comparisons, you generally want to use one of the $in, $all or $eq commands. I believe in your case you want find({ 'tags': {'$in': ['tag1', 'tag2']} }). See for example this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8145558/3657349 .

Use This, it may help:
collection_name.find({
  "tags": {
    "$all": ['tag1', 'tag2']
  }
})


Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Hi  @Tyler2P - thank you for you response. I have implemented your solution, however, I get the object address <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7c39fd7dfdf0>.
How do I get a readable document ?
